# How Do I Select Data From Single Column

Tags: sql

This is My `likes` Table in which likes for `postImages` and `pages` are stored using their ID's So Basically I want SELECT Query For Notifications Whenever user will like `pages` or `postImages` then their should be notification  for the SESSION user

Example- 
         userID(7) has Liked page_ID(7) ,
         userID(1) has Liked page_ID(5)

and I dont want those 0 values to be display in this list

```
    likeID  userID  post_ID     page_ID
        1     1        0           5
        2     1        0           7
        3     7        0           7
        4     7        1           0
        5     2        1           0
        6     2        9           0
        7     2        10          0
        8     2        6           0
        9     2        7           0
        10    2        0           7
        11    2        0           6
        12    2        0           5
        13    1       19           0
```

Comment: please change the tags, this is not a PHP question it is sql.  preferably you'd specify the flavor r.g. mysql.  Personally I also find the description not clear

Comment: perhaps you can expand on your desired results and show us what records you do want.  Because if you want when they like a post or when they like a page then all records would still be displayed as when page_id is not null post_id = 0 and vice versa

Comment: See What I want is 

When a user likes page then their should be notification for the session user that this this user has like this page 
Example If user 1 like pageID 3 then their should be notification that user 1 has like pageId 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pages:

```
SELECT likeID, userID, page_ID
FROM likes
WHERE NOT page_ID = 0
```

For posts:

```
SELECT likeID, userID, post_ID
FROM likes
WHERE NOT post_ID = 0
```

For a combined list:

```
SELECT likeID, userID, page_ID, null as post_ID
FROM likes
WHERE NOT page_ID = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT likeID, userID, null as page_id, post_ID
FROM likes
WHERE NOT post_ID = 0
```

Comment: The union all is definitely not needed if you construct the where statement correctly, and other than making the 0 null that query will still return all of the records in the table.  Which admittedly it is what OP seems to suggest they want..  But a couple of Case Statements with the right where and you have your answer....

Comment: So What should i used if it returns all the values ? if i get query for page then it still worked for